# Filter 11 Values with a Specific Search

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to separate players who are holders of a team. To find these 11 players, they start with one athlete who has (GK) and literally after another 10 players in a row, there will always be another athlete who starts with (GK). As I will do with multiple teams, I would like to do this filter automatically because each team has a different number of players, but all have in some position 10 players in between (GK). And these are the holders..

With this formula I tested, it failed because it filtered from the first (GK) and went to the last (GK)

How could I adjust to filter only when there are literally 10 players after one (GK) and after this tenth player, there will be another with (GK)?

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN("♦️", 1,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN("♦️", 1,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN("♦️", 1,A2:A), "GK(.*)"), "♦️"))), "(.*)GK"), "♦️"))), "GK(.*)"), "♦️"))
```

[image]

The problem with this format I'm trying to do is that it only works if there's a name with (GK) before 11 that I really want to get. If not, it generates an error. And I can't add the first (GK) of Lineup's 11 either.

[image]

The correct form I would like is in the image below (`Column LINEUP (11 Players)`) and in the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jnirW5Wkfcj4eSzM9In0_ChxRFl_KtBjgfnp1Qdi2ZY/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: @player0 done mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example

```
=offset(indirect("A"&arrayformula(vlookup(11,{filter(row(A2:A26),find("(GK)",A2:A26))-{0;array_constrain(filter(row(A2:A26),find("(GK)",A2:A26)),count(filter(row(A2:A26),find("(GK)",A2:A26)))-1,1)},filter(row(A2:A26),find("(GK)",A2:A26))},2,false))),-11,0,11,1)
```

Second example

```
=offset(indirect("G"&arrayformula(vlookup(11,{filter(row(G2:G26),find("(GK)",G2:G26))-{0;array_constrain(filter(row(G2:G26),find("(GK)",G2:G26)),count(filter(row(G2:G26),find("(GK)",G2:G26)))-1,1)},filter(row(G2:G26),find("(GK)",G2:G26))},2,false))),-11,0,11,1)
```

Comment: CodeCamper It worked perfectly, that's exactly what I needed, the same formula for all string sizes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=indirect(query(arrayformula( if(  if(REGEXMATCH(G2:G,".(GK)"),row(G2:G),0)-if(REGEXMATCH(G13:G,".(GK)"),row(G13:G),0)=-11, "G" & row(G2:G) & ":H" & row(G12:G),  )), "Select max(Col1) label max(Col1) ''"))
```

[image]

For more flexible and can be copied:

```
=indirect(query(arrayformula( if(  if(REGEXMATCH(G3:G,".(GK)"),row(G3:G),0) -
                               if(REGEXMATCH(G14:G,".(GK)"),row(G14:G),0)=-11, 
                                     REGEXEXTRACT(address(row(G1),COLUMN(G1)), "[A-Z]+") & row(G3:G) & ":" 
                                     & REGEXEXTRACT(address(row(H1),COLUMN(H1)), "[A-Z]+") & row(G13:G),  )), 
      "Select max(Col1) label max(Col1) ''"))
```

[image]

Comment: user11982798 Thanks a lot, but unfortunately this format will only work specifically on this listing. As I will import data from several teams with different numbers of players, this way will end up giving error. I'm struggling to get a general form that works for all teams, no matter how many players the team has. That when found 10 players between one (GK) and another (GK) that would be the correct filter.

Comment: with another listing you must change A and B (as column) according to your formula get

Comment: I add modified formula under image, this will be more flexible, and it can be copied well